# Adding dynamically generated buttons next to each other in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have tried finding examples of this problem, but can't find any that fits.

What I want is two buttons next to each other, from automatically generated list of buttons. The method `newAddButtonToLayout` is my try to make something that would do that.
I get this error when I run it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

at `row.addView(button)`

Here is activity code:

```
package com.code.p2_project.finalevaluationapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ExerciseList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Exercise> list = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
//This array holds the exercises
private ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
//This array holds the buttons
private ArrayList<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();//store them in ArrayList called exercises
private CategoryTypes categoryType;
private  TangibleTypes tangibleType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_list);
    LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.exerciseLayout); //The layout used to put the buttons in

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    categoryType = CategoryTypes.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("categoyType"));
    tangibleType = TangibleTypes.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("tangibleType"));
    System.out.println("Category sent was: "+categoryType);
    System.out.println("Tangible sent was: "+tangibleType);

    //Contruction and putting the objects into the aforementioned Exercise Array
    //TODO: Add this to the aforementioned method

    /*for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        list.add(new Exercise("Exercise "+i, CategoryTypes.MOBILITY, TangibleTypes.CHAIR, "Lav sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    }*/

    //Add BALANCE exercises here
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 1",CategoryTypes.BALANCE, TangibleTypes.CHAIR,"Lav sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 5",CategoryTypes.BALANCE, TangibleTypes.TABLE,"Mellem sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 1",CategoryTypes.BALANCE, TangibleTypes.CHAIR,"Lav sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));

    //Add STRENGTH exercises here
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 2",CategoryTypes.STRENGTH, TangibleTypes.BAND,"Mellem sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 2",CategoryTypes.STRENGTH, TangibleTypes.BAND,"Mellem sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 2",CategoryTypes.STRENGTH, TangibleTypes.BAND,"Mellem sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));

    //Add Mobility exercises here
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 3",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY, TangibleTypes.NOTHING,"Høj sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 6",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY,TangibleTypes.CHAIR,"Lav sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 3",CategoryTypes.MOBILITY, TangibleTypes.NOTHING,"Høj sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));

    //Add CARDIO exercises here
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 4",CategoryTypes.CARDIO, TangibleTypes.TABLE,"Høj sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 4",CategoryTypes.CARDIO, TangibleTypes.TABLE,"Høj sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));
    list.add(new Exercise("Øvelse 4",CategoryTypes.CARDIO, TangibleTypes.TABLE,"Høj sværhedsgrad",R.string.flexChair,this));




    exercises = filterExercises(categoryType,tangibleType);

    //Creating the buttons depending on the size of the list
    // and setting the names to the list names
    for (int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++)
    {
        MainActivity.makeButton(this, this, exercises.get(i).getExerciseName(), buttons, exercises.get(i).getColor(), i);

    }
    //Adding buttons to the layout and deleting the "wrong" buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
    {
        newAddButtonToLayout(buttons.get(i), relativeLayout, this, i);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_exercise_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//CategoryTypes categories = CategoryTypes.values()[which];

private ArrayList<Exercise> filterExercises (CategoryTypes categoryType, TangibleTypes tangibleType)
{
    for (Exercise exercise : this.list) {
        System.out.println("exercise"+exercise.toString());
        if (exercise.isCategoryType(categoryType) && exercise.isTangibleType(tangibleType)) {
            System.out.println("match");
            exercises.add(exercise);
        }
        else if (categoryType == CategoryTypes.ALL && tangibleType == TangibleTypes.ALL)
        {
            exercises.add(exercise);
        }
        else if (categoryType == CategoryTypes.ALL && exercise.isTangibleType(tangibleType))
        {
            exercises.add(exercise);
        }
        else if (exercise.isCategoryType(categoryType) && tangibleType == TangibleTypes.ALL)
        {
            exercises.add(exercise);
        }
    }
    return exercises;
}

public void sendWithData(int index)
{
    Intent sendToClass = new Intent (this, ExerciseView.class);
    sendToClass.putExtra("exerciseTitle",buttons.get(index).getText());
    sendToClass.putExtra("difficulty",exercises.get(index).getDifficulty());
    sendToClass.putExtra("description",R.string.flexChair);
    startActivity(sendToClass);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++) {
        if (view.getId() == i) {
            String buttonName = exercises.get(i).getExerciseName();
            switch (buttonName) {
                case "Øvelse 1":
                    sendWithData(i);
                    break;
                case "Øvelse 2": sendWithData(i);
                    break;
                case "Øvelse 3":
                    sendWithData(i);
                    break;
                case "Øvelse 4": sendWithData(i);
                    break;
                case "Øvelse 5":
                    sendWithData(i);
                    break;
                case "Øvelse 6": sendWithData(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}



public void newAddButtonToLayout (Button button, LinearLayout layout, Context context, int index)
{
    int counter = 0;        

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.setMargins(0,20,0,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    ArrayList<LinearLayout> rows = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
    {
        if (counter == buttons.get(i).getId())
        {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(context);
            row.setId(1000 + i);

            row.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);

            row.addView(button);
            layout.addView(row);

            counter += 2;

            rows.add(row);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++)
    {
        layout.addView(rows.get(i));
        System.out.println("Button's parent is: "+button.getParent());
    }

}

}
```

And the statically referenced makeButtons

```
public static void makeButton (Context context, View.OnClickListener view, String buttonText, ArrayList<Button> buttons, int colour, int id)
{
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf");

    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText(buttonText);
    button.setId(id);
    button.setOnClickListener(view);
    button.setBackgroundColor(colour);
    button.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
    button.setTextSize(25);
    button.setTypeface(tfBold);

    buttons.add(button);
    System.out.println(button.getId());
}
```

How to have 2 buttons in a view and add that for any number of buttons in buttons ArrayList? Without using ListView or Adapters?

(Note: I have tried finding the parent of button, but it is null)

Comment: you are adding same button twice ... (iterating `buttons` inside `buttons's` iteration - do you even understanding your code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly based on our private chat, good luck on styling.

```
public void newAddButtonToLayout (Context context)
{
int counter = 1;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        300);
params.weight = 1f;
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

ArrayList<LinearLayout> rows = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
{
    if (counter == buttons.get(i).getId())
    {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(context);
        row.setId(1000 + i);

        row.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        if(i <= buttons.size()) {
            if(i == buttons.size()) {
                if(buttons.size() % 2 == 0) {
                    buttons.get(i - 1).setLayoutParams(params);
                    row.addView(buttons.get(i - 1));
                }
            } else {
                buttons.get(i - 1).setLayoutParams(params);
                row.addView(buttons.get(i - 1));
            }

        }

        buttons.get(i).setLayoutParams(params);
        row.addView(buttons.get(i));
        //relativeLayout.addView(buttons.get(i));



        relativeLayout.addView(row);



        counter += 2;

        System.out.println(buttons.get(i).getId() + " BUTTON HERE");

        //rows.add(row);

    }
    if(i == buttons.size()-1) {
        System.out.println("IT IS IN THE LOOP");
        if(buttons.size() % 2 != 0) {
            buttons.get(i).setLayoutParams(params);
            relativeLayout.addView(buttons.get(buttons.size()-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do the adding of buttons twice for every button. Once here ->

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
{
    newAddButtonToLayout(buttons.get(i), relativeLayout, this, i);
}
```

and once in your `newAddButtonToLayout()` method. So I think you should transfor this method to:

```
public void newAddButtonToLayout (Button button, LinearLayout layout, Context context){   
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.setMargins(0,20,0,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that put one button in each layout?

Comment: Yes, it will, but this do your code too - rows (LinearLayouts) with a single button

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea how to do row with two buttons, new row with two buttons.

Comment: you can pass two buttons to your method that adds them to a LinearLayout and in this method you can create a single RelativeLayout, where to store both buttons one beside another (with a margin between them for example) and then add this Relativelayout to your main LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can use google  flexboxlayout to add buttons dynamically.

inside xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/thanks_bottom_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainRecepientLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:alignContent="flex_start"
            app:alignItems="flex_start"
            app:flexWrap="wrap" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

inside activity

```
  private void addRecepientList(ArrayList<User> recipientsOfThanks, FlexboxLayout layoutRecepient)
        {
       for (int i = 0; i < recipientsOfThanks.size(); i++) {
          LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


          layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
          layout.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
          layout.setLayoutParams(params);
          Button userLabel = new Button(getContext());
          userLabel.setLayoutParams(params);
          userLabel.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
          layout.addView(userLabel);
          layoutRecepient.addView(layout);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put in your xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:id="@+id/layoutInbox"
                android:background="#f4f3f8"></LinearLayout>
```

and put in your class a method and call it in OnCreate

```
private void buildInboxItems() {
final LinearLayout inboxLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutInbox);
            final String[] buttonsInfoList = new String[]{"image1#text1#1",
                    "image2#text2#2"};

        final List<Button> buttonsList = new ArrayList<Button>();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonsInfoList.length; i++) {
            final Button customButton = new Button(this);

            customButton.setId(100 + i);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if (i >= 0) {
                String image = buttonsInfoList[i];
                String[] parts = image.split("#");
                String imagePart = parts[0];
                String textPart = parts[1];
                final String tagPart = parts[2];

                Drawable img = GetImage(getApplicationContext(), imagePart);
                customButton.setTag(Integer.parseInt(tagPart));
                customButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, img, null, null);
                customButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                customButton.setText(textPart);
                customButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.CustomGray));
                customButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
                final int index = i;
                final int[] buttonIdsList = new int[buttonsInfoList.length];
                buttonIdsList[i] = index;
                customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        for (Button button : buttonsList) {
                            if (button.getId() == v.getId()) {
                                //  button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                Drawable imgOn = GetImage(getApplicationContext(), "imageButtonClicked");
                                button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.CustomOrange));
                                button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, imgOn, null, null);

                            } else {
                                //  button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                                Drawable imgOff = GetImage(getApplicationContext(), "imageButtonNotClicked");
                                button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.CustomGray));
                                button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, imgOff, null, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

//            setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            lp.setMargins(60, 5, 60, 5);
            lp.width = 120;
            lp.height = 150;
            inboxLayout.addView(customButton, lp);
            buttonsList.add(customButton);
        }
    }
```

i hope this will help, the buttons are drawn dynamically and the clicked one is highlighted..

Comment: I am not quite seeing how this can be integrated into my variables, and all the image part seems very arbitrary, but I am trying to implement it.

Comment: I tried implementing, but it seems to just add the buttons forever out to the right, never going on a new row.

Comment: you want them each in a row? if yes so just change `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Hawraa your code is obviously pasted without having the knowledge to explain, if you did, you would use more abstract concepts, not bring images and all the other stuff. Please don't confuse OP, help or don't.

Comment: it's my dummy code before connecting it to any service or database just not to add complexity to my answer!! and worked very fine to me :) @Bbit

Comment: sorry, just seemed too complex for such a simple question, it's usually appreciated to cut down on code just enough to understand the answer. So I thought you were just fishing for score, I apologize if that wasn't your intention, but I still feel that you should make your answer more readable and direct. As to make it useful at least for future people who need this answered.